# Should I use angular 8 with material design or semantic UI or mdbootstrap for my new data driven project

Tags: angular, angular-material, semantic-ui, mdbootstrap

Is angular 8 with material design is good or  with semantic UI or mdbootstrap. please advise in terms of speed, design, developer support, stability or any other concerning point.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit vague, but I gather you're deciding whether you want to use Material or Semantic UI frameworks. It basically boils down to what you think will look better for your application. Both have integrations with Angular and will be easy to use. Speed is not really relevant here since they're just design frameworks. Design is subjective, and both have community support.

So it's just up to you.

Comment: Please advise for mdbootstrap as compared to above options for new data driven project.